# What could be the problem related to the middleware function in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, store, middleware

Can't find a problem in my middleware func. It's been dispatching recursively. Please, help.

```
//App.js
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class App extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return <div>
        { (this.props.isLoading) ? <p>Loading...</p> : <p></p>}
        <button onClick={ this.props.send }>
        Hello {this.props.reducer}
        </button>
        </div>;
  }
}

export default connect(
    state => {
        return {
            reducer: state.value,
            isLoading: state.isLoading
        }
     }, {
        send: () => ({type: "SEND_REQUEST"})
    }
)(App);

//////////////////////////////
//index.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

const initialState = {
  isLoading: false,
  value: 1
};
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SEND_REQUEST":
      return { ...state, isLoading: true };
    case "SUCCESS_REQUEST":
      return { ...state, isLoading: false, value: parseInt(state.value) + 1 };
      case "ERROR_REQUEST":
      return { ...state, isLoading: false, value: "ERROR" };
    default:
      return state;
  }
  return state;
};
const middler = store => next => action => {
    fetch('http://ZiptasticAPI.com/90001', { method: 'GET'})
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(series => {
        console.log(series);
        store.dispatch({type: "SUCCESS_REQUEST"});
      })
      .catch(error => {
        store.dispatch({type: "ERROR_REQUEST"});
      });
};
const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(middler));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Can't find a problem in my middleware func. It's been dispatching recursively. Please, help. Just add some text to post my problem faster. I hope you'll understand. Sorry for mess. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your middleware is *always* running `fetch()`, for *every* dispatched action.  You should add a condition so that it only runs `fetch()` when it sees specific actions.  Also, your middleware isn't passing other actions onwards down the middleware pipeline, so no actions will ever reach the reducers.

Here's a fixed implementation:

```
const requestMiddleware = storeAPI => next => action => {
    if(action.type === "SEND_REQUEST") {
        fetch(someURL)
            .then(response => {
                // dispatch an action
            });
    }
    else {
        return next(action);
    }
}
```

Comment: I understood it already. Just couldn't find how to close the issue. Thanks a lot